# jQuery Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog

I have a delete button where on clicking the button i want a dialog box to pop up and then on clicking ok it should do the Ajax call else shouldnt do anything. here is Code

```
$('.comment-delete').click(function () {
    var deleteID = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "account/deleteComment/" + deleteID,

        success: function () {
            $("#comment-"+deleteID).slideUp("fast");
        }

    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Apart for what others said, consider using your own dialog page with jQuery for fancier look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (confirm("Your question")) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: "account/deleteComment/" + deleteID,
        success: function () {
            $("#comment-"+deleteID).slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking a question? I assume it's not working for you. I don't think you're passing the variables correctly. Take a look at jQuery.get(), that may be suitable for what you're trying to do.

Comment: this code is working. i wanted to add a dialog box like shall i delete this. if i click yes then it should delete else no action should take place.

Comment: I apologize, check other commenters for their answer. That should help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the dialog confirm with just a single extra line of code.

```
$('.comment-delete').click(function () {

    // Confirm Dialog.
    if (!confirm('Do you really want to delete?')) return false;

    var deleteID = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "account/deleteComment/" + deleteID,

        success: function () {
            $("#comment-"+deleteID).slideUp("fast");
        }

    });

    return false;
});
```